# Referencing nested class to get JQuery click to work

Tags: jquery, css, class, click, nested

I have a button that is supposed to toggle a div and I can't get the click function to point to the button. Any advice?

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="da-slider" class="da-slider">
        <div class="da-slide">
            <h2>About us</h2>
            <p>fsdffjasieffnain</p>
            <div id="test" class="da-link">Read more</div>
            <div class="da-img"><img src="images/1.png" alt="image01" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="layer1">  
        <h1 class="click">click</h1>  
         <div class="content">This is the text to hide</div>      
</div>
```

My Jquery code that doesn't work looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".content").hide();
        //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
        jQuery(".da-slider .da-slide .da-link").click(function() {
            jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Jquery code that does work looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".content").hide();
        //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
        jQuery(".click").click(function() {
            jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the element with `class="content"` in your HTML?

Comment: done, sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

It's cause you have no DIV `.content` as your `.next()` element. Try with:

```
jQuery(this).closest('.container').next("div").find('.content').slideToggle(500);
```

You have to take a more carefully look at all the DOM traversal methods that are offered by jQuery:

http://api.jquery.com

---

BTW, instead of rewriting all over the place the word `jQuery` go with:

```
jQuery(function( $ ) {
    $(".content").hide();
    $(".da-slider .da-slide .da-link").click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.container').next("div").find('.content').slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: I have the content here: <div class="content">test</div>. The content hides when i try clicking on a different element, it just can't find da-link for some reason

Comment: I've included the content element in the code. It's in a separate div outside container. I've got the code under the Jquery code (because I'm testing, it looks a bit messy right now)

Comment: I've changed the code to jQuery(this).closest('.container').next(".content").slideToggle(500); and it hasn't made a difference

Comment: @uubiz yes, hope mine is too ;)

Comment: still not working..maybe it's because my content div is not inside the container div?

Comment: @uubiz sure it's working, I don't know what's the issue on your side. Here's a demo: http://jsbin.com/acifev/1/edit